# Set focus on an element that has been partially rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form with an input element that updates a panel containing form elements on a `blur` event. I want the user to be able to navigate using the `tab` key. So leaving the first input using the `tab` should give focus to the first form element of the rendered form.

Input element with `blur` event:

```
<h:inputText class="text" id="profileLocation" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.profileLocation}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9])(?:\.(\d+))?(\.\d+)?(\.\d+)?" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="assertionLocationPanel" listener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.updateMessageLocation}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

It will render the `assertionLocationPanel` defined as:

```
<p:outputPanel id="assertionLocationPanel">
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.property}">
    </h:inputText>
</p:outputPanel>
```

When using the `tab` key, the panel is updated but the focus is not on the input element. I guess this is because of the rendering. If the panel is not updated, the focus is set to the correct element.

**Solution**

Call a javascript function specified in the `onevent` attribute:

```
<f:ajax event="blur" render="profileLocationErrorMessage assertionLocationPanel" listener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.updateMessageLocation}" onevent="setFocus"/>
```

the define the JS function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function setFocus() {
        $('#ConditionalComposite-ConditionalForm-1-ProfileLocation-segmentInstanceNumber').focus();
    }  
</script>
```

I had to call the JS function `setFocus` instead of calling `$('#ConditionalComposite-ConditionalForm-1-ProfileLocation-segmentInstanceNumber').focus();` in the `onevent` attribute because it did not work. I kept the generated ids because I use composite, also I redefined `javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR` to `-`.

If you using the regular `:` separator, you have to escape the separator as `#ConditionalComposite\\:ConditionalForm1\\:ProfileLocation\\:segmentInstanceNumber`.

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question, post it as an answer and accept it. This is the recommended practice. On another note, your javascript-function will execute the the `focus()` three times (once for each phase of the ajax-request). To prevent that, it should take a parameter called `data`, and only execute the `focus()` if `data.status == 'success'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this;

At first give an id to inputText under outpupanel.

```
<p:outputPanel id="assertionLocationPanel">
<h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.property}" id="assertioninput">
</h:inputText>
```

then add ajax complete event like this and oncomplete focus on the input you want.

```
<a4j:ajax event="complete"  render="assertionLocationPanel" oncomplete="assertioninput.focus();"/>
```

by the way dont forget to set form prependid=false in order to directly call the id of inputtext

Comment: I accept your answer because it helped me to find a solution. I updated my question with the solution inside. The concept is similar to what you advised. Thanks.